# Add #content to next_image_link()

Tags: gallery, navigation

I am almost completely happy with a new site I built - see http://www.fatasbutter.com.au/gallery/the-music/attachment/019/

As a final touch, I want to add `#content` to the end of the link location for each `previous_image_link()` and `next_image_link()`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda dirty, but I can't find a better hook:

```
function add_content_hash( $link ) { 
    $link = str_replace("' title='", "#content' title='", $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_content_hash' );
```

Answer (score 1):

For now I have included simple jQuery to tack `#content` on the end of the links:

```
$('#nav-below a,.attachment a').attr('href', function() {
  return this.href + '#content'
});
```

Obviously javascript is not a 100% solution, but it's certainly the simplest (only?) option at this point.